# Things gone past/The things gone past

Tags: articles

Is such a "the" as the one in my example optional, *i.e.*, when we specify some things but at the same time we mean any things fitting our specification.

> And then I understood things gone past are never to be found again (any things).
> And then I understood the things gone past are never to be found again (any things).

Comment: Can you fix your formatting. Every question you ask has this bullet list that just doesn't format properly Several of you questions have been fixed by others, but it is now time for you to start to learn how to use markdown to format your question yourself.

Comment: Native speakers wouldn't normally include the word ***gone*** in a context like *I understood things gone past are never to be found again.* See [this chart,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=knowledge+of+things+past%2Cknowledge+of+things+gone+past&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) showing that we always refer to *knowledge of **things past***, rather than *knowledge of things **gone** past*. Nor do we use the article here, but we *would* usually include the "relativiser" in OP's example: *And then I understood **that** things past are never to be found again*.

Comment: ...but note that this is a "high register, literary / poetic" usage that wouldn't normally occur in conversational contexts, so use it with caution.

Comment: To format a list, put in three spaces at the end of your line with returns.

Comment: @Lambie - formatting guide is in the edit box. Lists are double-return then asterisk space. I've fixed it just this once, but they need to learn to do it properly. Looking at it now, it shouldn't be a list anyway, it should be quote, which is double-return then >

Comment: @Tetsujin I do it by adding three spaces and a return.

Comment: @Lambie - two spaces & a return will make a new line. To make a list you need a leading char, `-` `+` `*` or `1.` at the head of a line, followed by a space. Indents in a list with 4 leading spaces.  Brief instructions are under the ? icon at the top of the edit box, full details linked from there.

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes, a new line and then * does it.  Why not write a comment that easily explains it to the OP instead of me?

Comment: @Lambie - I'm trying to correct *your* poor explanation. OP can look where I already explained, twice. I just thought you should have a look too, because *"put in three spaces at the end of your line with returns"* is simply wrong.

Comment: @Tetsujin Well, if you want a list without indenting it, three returns and then an asterisk will do it.

Comment: @Lambie - 1. That's not a list, it's just a new line with an asterisk at the head - unless you also add a space before typing. New lines greater than two are redacted by the system anyway. 2. That's not how you explained it. If you're going to try explain a function to a new user, at least get it right.

Comment: By way of explanation - though you can test this yourself live in the answer editor without having to submit - https://i.stack.imgur.com/YX8qn.png